# If logged_in conditional

Tags: templates, members, conditionals, users

I'm using an embedded template to include the  for my site.
I want to use [Google Analytics custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#visitorLevel) to track visitor information for logged in users so thought I could selectively show the Analytics code if a user is logged in using the {if logged_in} conditional.

So in a  tag have put the following:

```
{if logged_in}
// define a Visitor-level Custom Variables based on the member ID
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Member ID','{member_id}',1]); 
{/if}
```

If the user is logged in then the code works as expected.
However if a member is not logged in the template is writing the following to my HTML:

```
{if FALSE}
// define a Visitor-level Custom Variables based on the member ID
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Member ID','0',1]); 
{/if}
```

Any thoughts why this might be happening? I would expect that if nobody is logged in the site would return nothing.

Cheers,

Cole

Comment: I tried your exact code on 2.6.1 and it works fine, logged in or out. Is it possible there's something somewhere else that is disrupting the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your conditional is inside of `<script>` tags, EE by default prevents the advanced conditional from parsing. Add this to your config:

```
$config['protect_javascript'] = 'n';
```

Comment: Many thanks Siebird - that has fixed this issue :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using {if False} and instead using {if:else} and then specifying your analytics code from there.

Because you're not doing that, I would speculate that EE doesn't know what "else" to do and so just tries to go with what it has, which is nothing.